# Rails 4 - Devise 3 not working (NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationController#create )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Devise is not working the way it used to in Rails 4. I haven't changed anything in my Users model. It looks like this -

```
create_table(:users) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  t.timestamps
end

add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
```

My routes looks like this for devise -

```
devise_for :users, path: "", controllers: {
                   sessions: "users/session",
                   registrations: "users/registration",
                   passwords: "users/password"
               }, path_names: {
                   sign_in: 'login',
                   password: 'forgot',
                   confirmation: 'confirm',
                   unlock: 'unblock',
                   sign_up: 'register',
                   sign_out: 'logout'
               }
```

When I try to register from the default registration page, i.e. `registrations/new.html.erb`, I'm getting the following error -

> NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationController#create
>
> undefined method `deep_symbolize_keys' for #Array:0x007f8b33bcd750

My registration form looks like this (very basic) -

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><h5 class="color1">Sign up</h5></legend>

    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "Your first name", :autofocus => true %>

    <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Your last name" %>

    <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Your email address" %>

    <%= f.phone_field :phone_number, :placeholder => "Your phone number (Optional)" %>

    <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Your password" %>

    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Please confirm your password" %>

    <%= content_tag :button, :type => :submit, :class => "button small success" do %>
       Sign up
      <% end %>

 </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

**Solutions I've tried:**

1. I tried to update all the gems (including Devise which is currently at 3.4, used be 3.0), still no luck
2. Dropped the database, recreated again and ran all the migrations, no luck
3. Tried to create a new controller and inherit from Devise::RegistrationsController, no luck

**EDIT:** My controller code looks like this -

```
class Users::RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

`application.rb` looks like this -

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

What am I missing? Any help would be highly appreciated!

**Sorry for the really long question!**

Comment: Show you controller code

Comment: Show file config/application.rb and application_controller.rb

Comment: In that place should be hash, not array. Look at stack trace and devise sources to find the problem, they are rater simple.

Comment: Thanks Alex, it was rather simple and stupid. I don't know why the error wasn't obvious, I had to go through the full trace to see the i18n issue. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found what is going on.

As Alex suggested, I noticed that the error was occuring in `i18n` `store_translations` method.

I did some googling and I came across this - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/337

As Steven in that github thread pointed out, the one who reported the issue had some weird yml under `config/locales` and so did I.

I removed the `yml` and it seems to work just fine!